# Deleting an Azure Blob in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to delete blobs in an mvc 3 application that uses azure storage.

I'm trying to pass the Uri of the blob which will be deleted to the controller, however an error is thrown:

`A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:)`

I think this is from the `https:` part of the Uri and I need to parse it out, however I'm not sure how to do that. I'm wondering how to fix this error.

Is there a more graceful way to delete a blob from storage?

Comment: Search for that string ("A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected")... those search results should help. As to your second question, I don't follow. Maybe you can provide more about how you're doing the deletion and where you see room for improvement?

Comment: Haha, seems I beat you to the punch on that one. As with all questions, Google is the first source of answers.. I come here after I lose the will to keep on going. I tried some of the suggestions, one of the common one was a [ValidateInput(false)] attribute, however this did not work. Any other suggestions? As for the second question, I'm wondering if there is a way to go about deleting that's more in line with MVC? I have a view with a list of Blobs, when someone clicks a delete link, it sends the Blob's Uri back to the Controller (or it's suppose to.) I don't really care how it's deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it and I want to summarize the solution, since it requires bit from the other two answers and bits mostly from the [Scott Hanselman Blog post.](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx)

You need to do a few things to make this work:

- Put the `[ValidateInput(false)]` on your action method.
- Make sure your Url is properly encoded (an example is given in the above post) which is done when you use the `blobVariableName.Uri.AbsoluteUri` as the string to pass from your view to your controller, so you shouldn't have to do anything there.
- Make your query string looks like 
  `http://site/controller/action?blobid=http%3A%2F%2F...` and NOT `http://site/controller/action/http%3A%2F%2F...`  the latter won't work!

On a side note, since I started, our functional requirements changed and now were storing information about each blob in the database, which allows me to pass parameters other than the blob's uri, which seems like a much safer way to play it.

A great deal of the community appears to be in agreement that it is a bad idea to pass uri's and to open up your application as to allow you to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You must properly URL encode your urls. Here's an example of a badly encoded url:

```
http://foo.com/controller/action?param=http://bar.com
```

Here's how it should look like:

```
http://foo.com/controller/action?param=http%3A%2F%2Fbar.com
```

Or maybe you are having an url of the form:

```
http://foo.com/controller/action/https://bar.com
```

which is even worse. If you want to use special characters in the Path portion of an URL you might find the [following blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx) useful.

Comment: After reviewing the blog post it seems like a bad idea to be passing blob uri's around, is this true? Or is the blob the exception in this case?

Comment: @James, yes it is bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

If you want unsecure content to get through then you can add `[ValidateInput(false)]` to your action - however, this is opening up something that is there for your security - so only do this if you are sure you're code is secure - see first answer in [A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client)